# What is the purpose of Vue.use() while importing a plugin? If we have already used vue.use , is it required to add it to the components

Tags: vue.js

I'm using the plugin vue-flag-icon - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-flag-icon for flags, In their documentation I saw the following steps for initialising.

```
import FlagIcon from 'vue-flag-icon'
Vue.use(FlagIcon);
```

Do I need to have this? This is not specified in their docs!

```
export default {
    components: {
        FlagIcon. /// do i need to give it here ?
    },
}
```

What is the purpose of this `Vue.use(...)`, It's working fine even if I remove that. Can somebody help me out?

Checked the vue documentation - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html.

Did not get a clear idea about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vue.use automatically prevents you from using the same plugin more than once, so calling it multiple times on the same plugin will install the plugin only once.

For the `flag` component, it declares a global component that you can refer within your components, such that in the following example will render correctly.

in vue-flag-icon source code

```
install: function (Vue) {
    if (VuePlugin.installed) {
        return;
    }
    VuePlugin.installed = true;
    Vue.component('flag', Flag);
}
```

You can see that with `Vue.component('flag', Flag)` that this is a root level component declaration, therefore, in your components, you do not require to declare something like following

---

**Unnecessary if using Vue.use**

```
import { Flag } from "vue-flag-icon"

export default {
  components: { Flag }
}
```

---

If Vue.use is not used, the `flag` tag in the template will throw an error if you do not include it as a component within your vue init.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <flag iso="it" />
    <flag iso="gb" />
    <flag iso="us" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
}
</script>
```

Comment: It is working fine even when i removed the line Vue.use(FlagIcon); its not resulting in an error and its working fine

Comment: do you require flag anywhere in your vue application?

Comment: if you omit `Vue.use` - then you need `components: { Flag }`

Comment: Anyway what i understand from your answer is we only need. Another doubt is , if i want to use vue-flag in 3 vue files , I have to add these lines or import in all the 3 files right ? 

import FlagIcon from 'vue-flag-icon'
Vue.use(FlagIcon);
No need to initialise it in components right ?

Comment: I need flag in 3 diferent pages ! eg - dashboard.vue , ... 3 files

Comment: ok if you wish to use vue-flag in 3 vue files, use `Vue.use` - because it declares it as a global component - otherwise you will have to manually add FlagIcon to those 3 vue files

Comment: IF you do not declare it on the root level, or as a  `Vue.component('flag', Flag);` - Vue won't know what flag is